# Python3 beautifulsoup4 and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code for scraping score details from livescore.com . But I have some problems. Maybe I wrote incorrect code. Please help me.

Code run output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 15, in <module>
    box2 = box.find_all('a',{'class' : 'match-row scorelink'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://livescore.com')
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()
#page = requests.get('https://livescore.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')


box = soup.find('div',{'class':'container'})

box2 = box.find_all('a',{'class' : 'match-row scorelink'})

for data in box2:
    test = data.find('div',{'class': 'sco'}).text.replace('\n', '')
print (test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://livescore.com')
#page = requests.get('https://livescore.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

box = soup.find('div',{'class':'container'})

box2 = box.find_all('a',{'class' : 'match-row scorelink'})

for data in box2:
    test = data.find('div',{'class': 'sco'}).text.replace('\n', '')
print (test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. I have skipped 'box2' as it's not really needed for getting the scores. Also, judging by the data I fetched, `.replace('\n', '')` is not needed either, but feel free to use it if you think you will get score containing "\n" character.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://livescore.com')
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
box = soup.find('div',{'data-type':'container'})
scores=box.find_all('div',{'class': 'sco'})

for score in scores:
    print(score.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css selector.However `container` is not a class attrribute value.Its `data-type='container'` attribute value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://livescore.com')
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select("div[data-type='container'] .match-row.scorelink>.sco"):
    test=item.text.replace('\n', '')
    print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. Solved problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://livescore.com')
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()
#page = requests.get('https://livescore.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')


box = soup.find('div',{'data-type':'container'})

box2 = box.find_all('a',{'class' : 'match-row'})

for data in box2:
    test1 = data.find('div',{'class': 'sco'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    test2 = data.find('div',{'class': 'ply tright name'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    test3 = data.find('div',{'class': 'ply name'}).text.replace('\n', '')
    print(test2,test1,test3)
```